# Similar Apps Scripts Don't Work the Same - Why?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Two nearly identical functions in the same project triggered by triggers set up in the Triggers editor.

onWrongEdit(e) (triggered by onEdit) works but when I add "var sheet = e.range.getSheet().getName();" to onWrongInsert(e) (triggered by onChange) that second function fails even though it worked before adding that var line.

What the heck have I missed?

Feeling stupid. Be kind :)

```
function onWrongEdit(e){
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet().getName();
  var rangeCol = e.range.getColumn();
    if((sheet == 'Campaign Pipeline' && (rangeCol === 2 || rangeCol === 8 || rangeCol === 2)) || (sheet == 'Onboarding Pipeline' && (rangeCol === 2 || rangeCol === 3 || rangeCol === 4 || rangeCol === 5 || rangeCol === 11 || rangeCol === 12 ))){
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("STOP. Don't edit grey shaded cells. To fix, press CTRL+Z to undo. This error message will appear again, just ignore it.");
  }
}
```

```
function onWrongInsert(e){
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet().getName(); // The line that messes it up.
    if (e.changeType == 'INSERT_ROW'){  
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("STOP. You created a row the wrong way. Delete the row and use the 1POT menu.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Which trigger are you using?

Comment: onWrongEdit uses onEdit. onWrongInsert uses onChange

Comment: If one is using the onEdit trigger and the other is using the onChange trigger you should know that the event objects are not the same.  PLease add Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) to both function in order to see the event objects for each

Comment: Becareful with sharing the event object because you just shared you email address with everyone on SO.

Comment: I used var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName(); to get the sheet name rather than the event object because onChange doesn't do the source object. Sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is from the executions page

```
Aug 25, 2022, 11:19:26 AM   Info    {"authMode":"FULL","changeType":"INSERT_ROW","source":{},"triggerUid":"","user":{"email":"","nickname":""}}


Aug 25, 2022, 11:19:26 AM   Error   TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheet' of undefined
    at onWrongInsert(ag1:19:23)
```

> It occurs because there is no range element in the event object for onChange

I rewrote them like below:

```
function onWrongEdit(e){
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var name = e.range.getSheet().getName();
    if((name == 'Sheet0' && (e.range.columnStart === 2 || e.range.columnStart === 8)) || (name == 'Sheet1' && (e.range.columnStart === 2 || e.range.columnStart === 3 || e.range.columnStart === 4 || e.range.columnStart === 5 || e.range.columnStart === 11 || e.range.columnStart === 12 ))){
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("STOP. Don't edit grey shaded cells. To fix, press CTRL+Z to undo. This error message will appear again, just ignore it.");
  }
}
function onWrongInsert(e){
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet().getName(); // The line that messes it up.
    if (e.changeType == 'INSERT_ROW'){  
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("STOP. You created a row the wrong way. Delete the row and use the 1POT menu.");
    }
}

function createTriggers() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onWrongEdit').forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onEdit().create();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onWrongInsert').forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onChange().create();
}
```